# Storybook7: True way to create mobile stories out of desktop ones

Tags: reactjs, migration, storybook

I'm currently migrating from Storybook 6 to 7 and having issues with re-export story mechanic.

My project has a lot of stories in couples desktop/mobile based on prop "layout" passed to components. It's done like this

```
// desktop.stories.tsx
import { Demo } from './index'
import type { Layout } from './index'

export interface StoryType {
  (args: { layout?: Layout }): JSX.Element
}

export default {
  title: 'demo/desktop',
  args: { layout: 'desktop' },
}

export const Story: StoryType = ({ layout }) => <Demo layout={layout} />
```

```
// mobile.stories.tsx
export default {
  title: 'demo/mobile',
  args: { layout: 'mobile' },
}

export * from './desktop.stories'
```

It's made like this so we don't have to add new story twice - for desktop and mobile layout.

But on storybook 7 mobile file fails eslint check with "The file should have at least one story export" (eslintstorybook/story-exports). And mobile story doesn't get to storybook, only desktop one is shown.

What is the best approach to this problem now? Except copy pasting story obviously

```
// Demo Component itself for reference
import type { FC } from 'react'

export type Layout = 'desktop' | 'mobile'

interface Props {
  layout?: Layout
}

export const Demo: FC<Props> = ({ layout }) => <div>{layout === 'mobile' ? 'MOBILE' : 'DESKTOP'}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

adding this solves the problem:

```
  // .storybook/main.ts
  features: {
    storyStoreV7: false,
  }
```

Explanation: this feature turned on by default and loads stories on demand. This way reexport wont work. Turning it off has downsides that explained in official documentation: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/overview#known-limitations